# Add domain machine user to local admins

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have two machines, say in the company domain `CorpotateDomain`.
First machine: `first.CorpotateDomain.com`
Second: `second.CorpotateDomain.com`

I want to add `PrimUser` from the first one to administrators group for second machine using powershell.
And then i want to shutdown second machine from the first one (login using `PrimUser`) using the `shutdown` utility or `stop-computer` cmdlet. (Or, for example, restart `iis` remotely)

Is it possible, and what command should i use to add domain users to admins?

p.s.
i tried:

```
$user = "WinNT://first.CorpotateDomain.com/PrimUser"
$group = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Administrators")
$group.PSBase.Invoke("Add",$user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a domain user to the local admin group but i don't think you can add a local user of another computer.

```
$user=[ADSI]"WinNT://domain/PrimUser"
$group=[ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators"
$group.Psbase.Invoke("Add",$user.Psbase.path)
```

Comment: i can add domain user to local admins using windows control panel, and as it so, i think should be way to do it via powershell

Answer (score 0):

Set $user to the user's distinguished name, something like `CN=PrimUser,CN=Users,DC=CorporateDomain,DC=com`.